# Search Function Flask SQLAlchemy Page Refreshes Instead of Showing Results

Tags: sqlite, flask, search, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing a Search page for my website, using Python, Sqlite, and SqlAlchemy. I designed this form with two HTML pages - on the first page, I have a drop down box and a submit button; when the user selects from the Drop Down and hits submit, they should be directed to the second HTML page, which will list the results. Instead, upon hitting submit, the first page simply refreshes instead of going to the second page.

In an attempt to rectify this, I tried to follow the answers given to these two similar questions, but I could not get mine to work:

([How to create a search functionality in Flask that will be based on query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77526573/how-to-create-a-search-functionality-in-flask-that-will-be-based-on-query-parame))
and ([search function (query in Flask, SQLAlchemy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579400/search-function-query-in-flask-sqlalchemy))

Here are the relevant pieces of code from my app.py file:

```
# Models: Here is where I lay out my table details:
class Profile(db.Model):
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    merchant = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    cMerchantOther = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=False, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    drcr = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    pmtmethod = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    invoiceDate = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Category : {self.category}, Price: {self.price}"
    
# Here is where I reference my Search page:
@app.route('/SearchCash1', methods=["POST","GET"])
def SearchCash1():
    return render_template('SearchCash.html')

# Here is where I perform the query to search for, and display, the data:
@app.route('/SearchCashDisplay' , methods=["GET"])
def SearchCashDisplay():
    SearchCash1 = SearchCash1()
    profileSearch = Profile.query
    profileSearch = profileSearch.filter(Profile.merchant.like( SearchCash1.merchant.data ))
    profileSearch = profileSearch.order_by(Profile.invoiceDate).all()
    return render_template('SearchCashDisplay.html', profileSearch=profileSearch)

# Here is where I perform a delete function, to use as part of the display form
@app.route('/delete14/<int:id>')
def erase14(id):
    data = Profile.query.get(id)
    db.session.delete(data)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect('/SearchCashDisplay')
```

Here is the Search Form:

```
SearchCash.html

<html>
<head>
    <title>Cash Search by Merchant</title>
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'style/style1.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Search a Merchant:</h3>
    <form action="/SearchCash1" method="POST">
        <label>Select a Merchant</label>
            <select name="merchant">
             <option value="Cherokee Carpet">Cherokee Carpet</option>
             <option value="Collins Aikman">Collins Aikman</option>
             <option value="Couristan">Couristan</option>
             <option value="Masland">Masland</option>
             <option value="Mohawk Industries">Mohawk Industries</option>
             <option value="Shaw">Shaw</option>
            </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the HTML display page:

```
SearchCashDisplay.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search Cash Results Page</title>
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'style/style1.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>View Merchant</h3>
    
    
    <br>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Merchant</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>drcr</th>
            <th>category</th>
            <th>Invoice Date</th>
            <th>pmtmethod</th>
            <th>cMerchantOther</th>
            <th>#</th>
        </thead>
        {% for data in SearchCashDisplay %}
        <tbody>
            <td>{{data.id}}</td>
            <td>{{data.merchant}}</td>
            <td>{{data.price}}</td>
            <td>{{data.drcr}}</td>
            <td>{{data.category}}</td>
            <td>{{data.invoiceDate}}</td>
            <td>{{data.pmtmethod}}</td>
            <td>{{data.cMerchantOther}}</td>
            <td><a href="/delete14/{{data.id}}" type="button">Delete</a></td>
        </tbody>
        {% endfor%}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form `<form action="/SearchCash1" method="POST">` POSTs to `/SearchCash1` and the handler for that URL does nothing.  Change the value of the `action` attribute to the URL of the route that processes your search form.

Comment: Thank you, Snakecharmerb. I tried your suggestion and received an internal server error: in SearchCashDisplay SearchCash1 = SearchCash1() : cannot access local variable 'SearchCash1' where it is not associated with a value. Researching this error message, I see that this is an issue related to Global variables - the variable must be made global in order to be recognized. However, I do not see how to make this global, as my text editor throws errors when I use the word Global.